# GROUP BY em query com coluna por subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho o seguinte select:

```
SELECT A.CARRO,
(SELECT TOP 1 VALOR FROM tab2 B WHERE B.DATA <= A.DATA ORDER BY B.DATA DESC) VALOR
FROM tab1 A
```

> Em `(SELECT TOP 1 VALOR FROM tab2 B WHERE B.DATA <= A.DATA ORDER BY
>   B.DATA DESC)` irá me trazer o `VALOR` referente a aquela `DATA` ou a
>   "mais recente".

---

Tentei fazer, um `GROUP BY` por `CARRO`, várias formas, uma delas:

```
SELECT A.CARRO,
SUM((SELECT TOP 1 VALOR FROM tab2 B WHERE B.DATA <= A.DATA )) VALOR
FROM tab1 A
GROUP BY A.CARRO
```

Mas me retorna erro:

> Não é possível executar uma função de agregação em uma expressão que contenha um agregado ou uma subconsulta.

---

- Realmente não tem como fazer o `GROUP BY` se tem uma subquery para trazer valor da coluna?
- Seria por causa da "sequência sistêmica" que o SQL trabalha, ou algo do tipo?
- Quais outras formas poderia fazer para obter o resultado?

Comment: *"não tem como fazer o GROUP BY se tem uma subquery"* infelizmente não. Você teria de colocar tudo numa tabela temporária por exemplo para poder agrupar. Pense o `group by` e as funções de agregação trabalham "em conjunto", para produzir o resultado da query, mas uma subquery prejudica isso

Comment: Qual o motivo do GROUP BY? A tabela `tab1` possui mais de uma linha para um mesmo valor de `CARRO`? // Não existe uma correlação entre `tab1` e `tab2` pela coluna `CARRO`?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Posso então criar uma view né!?... seria mais fácil que tabela temporária

Comment: @JoséDiz sim, possui vários registros, e não, sem relação. A relação entre eles ainda é bem pior do que nesse exemplo ! 

Comment: A solução seria fazer um `JOIN` com um `SELECT` onde esteja a soma do valor agrupada por `CARRO`, mas aí tinha que existir uma relação entre a `tab1` e a `tab2`.

Comment: @JoãoMartins Ah sim... mas infelizmente não tem relação. 

Comment: E será que não devia? Caso contrário como sabe que registos na tabela `tab1` dizem respeito aos da `tab2`?

Comment: @JoãoMartins Não. Tem muito mais join e select na query. A relação é mínima perto do grande período. Além de que nem tem como, pois é um sistema que eu posso criar tabelas em camada cliente só. 100% descartada.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Talvez o uso de CTE resolva e até deixe o código mais legível.

```
-- código #1
with CadaCarro as (
SELECT A.CARRO,
       (SELECT top (1) B.VALOR 
          from tab2 as B 
          where B.DATA <= A.DATA 
          order by B.DATA desc) as VALOR
  from tab1 as A
)
SELECT CARRO, sum(VALOR) as somaVALOR
  from CadaCarro
  group by CARRO;
```

No [Porto SQL](http://portosql.wordpress.com/artigos/) há um artigo sobre programação modular em T-SQL através do uso de CTE.

Comment: Cara, matou a pau! 