# Condição em campo com subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

Exemplo do select:

```
SELECT campo1,
(ROUND(((t3.quantidade * t2.distancia *
(SELECT TOP 1 valor FROM frete WHERE datainicio <= t1.dataemissao AND tipo = t4.tipo ORDER BY DATAINICIO DESC))
- (t1.fretevalor - t5.pedagios))
/ (SELECT TOP 1 valor FROM diesel WHERE datainicio <= t1.dataemissao ORDER BY datainicio DESC),3)) saldo
FROM tabela1 t1
LEFT ...
```

Nesse exemplo, tenho somente **2 colunas** (`campo1` e `saldo`), sendo o `saldo` calculado por subquerys (*e assim deve manter-se*).

*Não vem ao caso trazer todas as relações (JOINS), pois o campo está calculando corretamente e não deve ser alterado. A questão é como criar a condição para a coluna `saldo`, conforme seu valor.*

---

Ocorre que, **as vezes** o valor da coluna `saldo` vem **negativo**, então neste caso, gostaria de colocá-lo como valor `0`.

Consigo fazer com `CASE`, mas eu teria que **repetir 2x** toda essa consulta (ou não!?), exemplo:

```
SELECT campo1, ROUND((CASE WHEN 
(((t3.quantidade * t2.distancia *
(SELECT TOP 1 valor FROM frete WHERE datainicio <= t1.dataemissao AND tipo = t4.tipo ORDER BY DATAINICIO DESC))
- (t1.fretevalor - t5.pedagios))
/ (SELECT TOP 1 valor FROM diesel WHERE datainicio <= t1.dataemissao ORDER BY datainicio DESC)) < 0 
THEN 0 ELSE 
(((t3.quantidade * t2.distancia *
(SELECT TOP 1 valor FROM frete WHERE datainicio <= t1.dataemissao AND tipo = t4.tipo ORDER BY DATAINICIO DESC))
- (t1.fretevalor - t5.pedagios))
/ (SELECT TOP 1 valor FROM diesel WHERE datainicio <= t1.dataemissao ORDER BY datainicio DESC))END),3) saldo
FROM tabela1 t1
LEFT ...
```

---

- Existe outra forma de **comparar o valor** como o `CASE` mas **sem repetir** toda a subquery (como no exemplo)?

Comment: pode usar variável?

Comment: @ThiagoMagalhães eu acho que não dá certo porque ele puxa as subquerys linha por linha, não é?! A não ser que você crie uma variável @saldo, e já utilize ela para o `CASE`. Seria isso? Se não for, aí não faço ideia. 

Comment: Criar uma função para calcular o saldo pode ser uma solução interessante.

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade não posso, tem que ser direto nessa query. Estou usando o `CASE` mesmo, funcionando, mas abri a questão para ver se existe uma forma melhor que não exija duplicar todo o código. 

Comment: Avalie utilizar APPLY no lugar das subconsultas de diesel e frete. // Quando o código começa a ficar nebuloso, é porque já passou da hora de utilizar CTE...  ;)

Comment: @JoséDiz  muito boa! O APPLY seria o `with`?

Comment: @rbz Não. o `with` é CTE, conforme solução proposta abaixo. Quando possível leia o artigo sugerido.

Comment: @JoséDiz eu achei o artigo do CTE, dei uma olhada por cima, realmente muito bom, irei ler na íntegra o quanto antes! Sobre o `APPLY` pelo que achei, só usa em funções, aí não tem como fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avalie o uso de CTE para tornar o código legível e de fácil manutenção.

```
-- código #1 v3
;with 
ColetaDados as (
SELECT campo1, t3.quantidade, t2.distancia,
       (SELECT TOP (1) f.valor FROM frete as f WHERE f.datainicio <= t1.dataemissao AND f.tipo = t4.tipo ORDER BY f.DATAINICIO DESC) as valor_frete,
       t1.fretevalor, t5.pedagios,
       (SELECT TOP (1) d.valor FROM diesel as d WHERE d.datainicio <= t1.dataemissao ORDER BY d.datainicio DESC) as valor_diesel
  from tabela1 t1
       left ...
),
CalculoSaldo as (
SELECT campo1, 
       case when valor_diesel = 0 then NULL
            else (((quantidade * distancia * valor_frete) - (fretevalor - pedagios)) / valor_diesel) end as pre_saldo
  from ColetaDados
)
SELECT campo1, 
       saldo= round (case when pre_saldo < 0 then 0 else pre_saldo end, 3) as saldo
  from CalculoSaldo;
```

Verifique com atenção se as fórmulas estão corretas; posso ter esquecido de algo.

A CTE ColetaSaldo somente obtém os dados, sem efetuar qualquer cálculo. A segunda CTE, CalculoSaldo, efetua o cálculo do saldo segundo a fórmula. Ao final, o SELECT faz o tratamento de valor negativo e arredonda o valor para 3 casas decimais. Um passo de cada vez. Internamente o otimizador junta tudo em um único comando e gera o plano de execução.

No caso de subconsultas correlacionadas sugiro que sempre identifique as colunas com *alias*.

Quando possível leia o artigo “Programação modular com expressões de tabela (CTE)”, que está na seção Artigos de [Porto SQL](https://portosql.wordpress.com/artigos/).

---

Para esse caso me parece que também é possível utilizar APPLY no lugar das subconsultas correlacionadas. Talvez fique até mais eficiente.

Comment: @rbz Acrescentei o título do artigo na resposta acima, ok?

Comment: Eu confundi essa resposta com a da pergunta [GROUP BY em query com coluna por subquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/320901/group-by-em-query-com-coluna-por-subquery/320919#320919)... Na verdade sua resposta deve funcionar, mas está usando o `WITH`. Então no caso "não existe" uma forma diretamente na linha, como o `CASE`. Só adiciona no começo da resposta pra ficar certinho, e usando o `WITH` como alternativa. Valeu ✌️

Comment: @rbz Não sei se entendi direito sua última observação. O `CASE` permanece no código, só que de uma forma limpa. Observe na penúltima linha do código que está `round (case when pre_saldo < 0 then 0 else pre_saldo end`.   O `pre-saldo` é equivalente a toda aquela expressão matemática. Seria a respeito disso o comentário?

Comment: Mais ou menos. Eu acho que não mudaria muito porque eu preciso comparar as datas e tipo: `WHERE datainicio <= t1.dataemissao AND tipo = t4.tipo`, da forma que fez, não está passando essa parâmetro, não é!?

Comment: José, eu até vou desmarcar a resposta (mas deixar o +1), para não confundir, até nós acertamos a resposta final, e até não atrapalhar caso alguém consulte ok!? ✌️

Comment: @rbz As datas estão sendo comparadas. Veja na CTE ColetaDados.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81414/discussion-between-jose-diz-and-rbz).